# How to store a variable in local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running a script and I am using a `meta refresh` as it could stop due to internet connection or server downtimes or anything:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

The script requires a starting variable, this will update every time the scripts runs, so I want to save the latest value for that variable in local storage but by putting it this way, the value will always be overwritten to the starting value

```
var myId = 47911111;
localStorage.setItem('titles', myId);
```

Comment: You already using `localStorage.setItem()`, then what else is the issue

Comment: as i stated in the question, will it not be overwritten when the page refreshes? I mean will not `myId` be back as `47911111` ? @JijoCleetus

Comment: You should try closure in this case

Comment: @JijoCleetus what do you mean? may you elaborate it into an answer pls?

Comment: My point was you could simply check for an `undefined` check. If undefined, fill with `47911111` else do nothing. So in the next refresh it wont update the latest value with `47911111`.
Second way is to use a closure (function which is returning another expression). Let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if your browser supports local storage like this (**local storage will persist across page refreshes unlike sessionStorage**)

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
    // Store value
    localStorage.setItem("keyName", variable);
   // Retrieve value from local storage and assign to variable
   var myId = localStorage.getItem("keyName");
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

Comment: as i stated in the question, will it not be overwritten when the page refreshes? I mean will not `myId` be back as `47911111` ?

Comment: you need to assign the value back to myID variable using localStorage

Comment: sorry could you elaborate that comment in your answer please and reflect the id as per the quetsion?

Comment: where are you storing `var myId = 47911111;`?

Comment: if I do     `var myId = 47911111;
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            localStorage.setItem("keyName", myId);
            var myId = localStorage.getItem("keyName");
      }` then when the page refresh `myid` will be again `47911111` right?

Comment: Well it is what I am trying to resolve then, because I want the new variable not the original

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151873/discussion-between-rob-m-and-ankit-sharma).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming localStorage is available and I understood your issue:

```
// first declare a variable but don't assign a value
var myId;
// then check whether your localStorage item already exists ...
if (localStorage.getItem('titles')) {
    // if so, increase the value and assign it to your variable
    myId = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('titles')) + 1;
    // and reset the localStorage item with the new value
    localStorage.setItem('titles', myId);
} else {
    // if localStorage item does not exist yet initialize
    // it with your strat value
    localStorage.setItem('titles', 1);
    // and assign start value to your variable
    myId = paresInt(localStorage.getItem('titles'));
}
console.log(myId);
```

Now each time the page loads the code checks whether there is a localStorage item "titles".

If so, the value of "titles" is increased by 1 and the resulting value is assigned to "myId".

If the localStorage item is not there yet it's initialized with the start value and the start value is assigned to "myId" as well.

Note that localStorage keys and values are always strings and that an integer value is always converted to a string.